# php - exec issue

Tags: php, exec

I'm setting up a new server and of course I didn't document every change I did to the last one but I'm getting there.

I have a weird issue, I'm trying to do a simple call in php:

```
exec('service httpd reload');
```

And it's not doing anything. I can execute other commands such as tar, I did check php.ini for disabled_functions and it's empty. The username php is using for creating files/folders is "apache" as well.

Does anyone know any other areas I can check? This is a fresh install of php 5.2.x so I'm sure there is a security setting in apache or something blocking this.

Comment: Should also note the error message in system('service httpd reload') is Reloading httpd: [FAILED]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your apache is most probably running under a **normal user account** (www-data or apache - it depends on your distribution), but to restart apache (or any other service) you have to be **root**.

You could use [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to elevate your privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You can't restart Apache as a normal user, but you should **never** leave your root password written in a file. If you really have to run that command from php, there's an alternative method.

You can allow certain commands to be run as root by a certain user without specifying a password. To do this you must edit the `/etc/sudoers` file with `visudo` and add the tag NOPASSWD to the command you want to run. Here is the example from the man page:

```
ray    rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm
```

This would allow the user ray to run /bin/kill, /bin/ls, and /usr/bin/lprm as root on the machine rushmore without authenticating himself.